# unexpected token 'export' when using typeorm in heroku

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku, nestjs, typeorm

I am follwing [this](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/4068) thread on how to get TypeORM and PostgreSQL to work in Heroku.

Using `ormconfig.js` and `module.exports` I get this error

```
MissingDriverError: Wrong driver: "undefined" given. Supported drivers are: "cordova", "expo", "mariadb", "mongodb", "mssql", "mysql", "oracle", "postgres", "sqlite", "sqljs", "react-native".
```

```
const env = require('dotenv')
env.config()

module.exports = {
  name: 'default',
  type: process.env.DATABASE_TYPE,
  host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
  port: 5432,
  username: process.env.DATABASE_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
  synchronize: true,
  dropSchema: false,
  logging: true,
  entities: ['/src/**/*.entity.ts', 'dist/**/*.entity.js'],
  extra: {
    ssl: true,
  },
};
```

The above link says switch to `.ts` and use `export`

so..using `ormconfig.ts` and `export = config` I get this error:

```
2020-03-25T05:07:57.946988+00:00 app[web.1]: export = config
2020-03-25T05:07:57.946988+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^
2020-03-25T05:07:57.946988+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-03-25T05:07:57.946989+00:00 app[web.1]: SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

```
const config = {
  name: 'default',
  type: process.env.DATABASE_TYPE,
  host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
  port: 5432,
  username: process.env.DATABASE_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
  synchronize: true,
  dropSchema: false,
  logging: true,
  entities: ['/src/**/*.entity.ts', 'dist/**/*.entity.js'],
  extra: {
    ssl: true,
  },
};

export = config;
```

I've also tried using `export default` but had same error as with export...

Not exactly sure where to go from here...anyone had this issues?

does babel need to be included to run my node.js apps in heroku?

Answer (score 1):

**Do it this way to get rid of (2020-03-25T05:07:57.946989+00:00 app[web.1]: SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export') error:**

```
exports.config = {
  name: 'default',
  type: process.env.DATABASE_TYPE,
  host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
  port: 5432,
  username: process.env.DATABASE_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
  synchronize: true,
  dropSchema: false,
  logging: true,
  entities: ['/src/**/*.entity.ts', 'dist/**/*.entity.js'],
  extra: {
    ssl: true,
  },
};
```

Comment: following this approach I get `MissingDriverError` that I mentioned above

Comment: May I see a sample code where you are creating a DB connection?

Comment: in TypeORM if there is a file called `ormconfig` then typeorm uses that as the db connection file. The only other thing I am doing is calling `TypeOrmModule.forRoot()` in my `app.module.ts`

Comment: Do you have the environment variable `DATABASE_TYPE` set in Heroku? Heroku by default give a `DATABASE_URL` that you have to manually parse into it's proper parts if you don't just pass the URL to your database connector

Comment: @JayMcDoniel Yes I set the `DATABASE_TYPE` variable in my variables section in heroku. I have also noticed that `tsconfig.json` was including `ormconfig.js` not `.ts` so I changed that which I think solved the problem I was having?? now on to the next problem where Heroku cannot find `app/dist/main.js`

Answer (score 0):

ormconfig MUST keep the `.js` extension.

Also, I am parsing the `DATABASE_URL` from Heroku and adding all the variables into their appropriate placeholders in `ormconfig` like so:

```
const parse = require('pg-connection-string').parse;
const env = require('dotenv')
env.config()

const config = parse(process.env.DATABASE_URL)

const pgConnection  = {
  type: "postgres",
  host: config.host,
  port: config.port,
  username: config.user,
  password: config.password,
  database: config.database,
  synchronize: true,
  dropSchema: false,
  logging: true,
  entities: ['/src/**/*.entity.ts', 'dist/**/*.entity.js'],
  extra: {
    ssl: true,
  }
}

module.exports = pgConnection;
```